# How can I call method in the component from view? (vue.js 2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My view is like this :

```
<div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
        <div class="wrap-tabs">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-cat">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" @click="getPlayer(1)">England</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" @click="getPlayer(2)">Spain</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" @click="getPlayer(3)">Italy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active">
        <top-player-view country_id="1"></top-player-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

My component top player view is like this :

```
<template>    
    ...
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        props:['country_id'],
        created() {
            this.$store.dispatch('getTopPlayers', this.country_id)
        }
        methods: {
            getPlayer: function(country_id) {
                 this.$store.dispatch('getTopPlayers', country_id)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I try call getPlayer method in top player view component. I call the method from view. You can see my code above

When I click the tab, I check on the console exist error :

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "getPlayer" is not defined on the
>   instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive
>   data properties in the data option.  (found in root instance)
>
> Uncaught TypeError: getPlayer is not a function

How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you using `vue-loader`?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken in Vue2 created() is replaced for mounted().

Comment: @Daniel T., No. Seems I did not use it

Comment: @peaceman, Seems the problem is not there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually call the method *on* the element.

One solution:
add `ref="player"` to your `top-player-view` and then call `$refs.player.getPlayer(1)` instead of just `getPlayer(1)`